# Zero divizors in $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle 4x^3,15 \rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

We are in the quotient ring $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle 4x^3,15 \rangle$. $I=\langle 4x^3,15 \rangle$.

We want to check if $3+I$ and $x+I$ are zero devisors in $R$.

*Answer:* First we will show that $3+I \neq I$. 
If $3+I=I \iff3\in I\iff\exists a(x),b(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]:3=a(x)4x^3+b(x)15$ and if we put $x=0\implies3=b(0)15 \implies b(0) \not \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, contradiction. Working in the same way $5+I\neq I$, but $(3+I)(5+I)=15+I=I$. So, $3+I$ is a zero devisor in R.

Can we do the same for $x+I$? $x+I\neq I $ because if $x+I=I \iff x\in I\iff\exists c(x),d(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]:x=c(x)4x^3+d(x)15 \iff x(1-4x^2c(x))=15d(x)$
In this case it's not helpful to put $x=0$. What about $x=2$? we have $d(2)=(2/15)(1-16c(2))$. Is this a contradiction? And, also, do we have a better way to prove this?

Comment: I can't see  why need to show $3+I\ne I$. As far as I know, $0$ is a zero-divisor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the equality $x=c(x)4x^3+d(x)15$ is impossible. Indeed, let $c(x)=\sum_kc_kx^k$ and the same for $d$. The term of first degree of RHS is $15d_1x$, but it is $x$ in LHS.

Comment: Is this enough? Is that I wrote for $x +I$ (if we put $x=2$) wrong?

Comment: I don't see how $15d(2)=2(1-16c(2))$ is a contradiction. It could be, but it is not obvious. The equality holds, for example, if $c(2)=1$ and $d(2)=-2$.